Persistent Network Unclaimed
Following up on questions like this, this and this (as well as some others).
The problem is that after installing an update and rebooting, I am unable to connect to WiFi. In particular, running sudo lshw -c network shows, that wireless adapter and/or network port are unclaimed. The first time it happened, I followed the advices on other posts and that solved it. However, the problem is persistant and occurs every time I reboot after an update. Furthermore, I found out that the problem "fixes" itself when I restart my computer many times. Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it? Many thanks in advance! :)
Details
I am running on 22.04.2-Ubuntu, kernel version 6.5.0-41-generic, dual boot with Windows 11. At the moment, everything works. Running sudo lshw -c network outputs:
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 1a
       serial: ac:12:03:41:60:cc
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.5.0-41-generic firmware=77.2df8986f.0 cc-a0-77.ucode ip=192.168.1.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:71 memory:fc800000-fc803fff

running sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status outputs:
Status: install ok installed

and running sudo dmesg | grep iwl outputs:
[    3.852838] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.857474] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected crf-id 0x3617, cnv-id 0x100530 wfpm id 0x80000000
[    3.857498] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: PCI dev 2723/0084, rev=0x340, rfid=0x10a100
[    3.867065] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    3.867085] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    3.867647] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 77.2df8986f.0 cc-a0-77.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.210410] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    4.335501] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected RF HR B3, rfid=0x10a100
[    4.400804] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: ac:12:03:41:60:cc
[    4.460598] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.793735] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 0
[16346.129024] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: reached 20 old SN frames from e0:b9:e5:a6:fe:07 on queue 1, stopping BA session on TID 0
[16539.520314] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: reached 20 old SN frames from e0:b9:e5:a6:fe:07 on queue 1, stopping BA session on TID 0
[17895.657505] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: reached 20 old SN frames from e0:b9:e5:a6:fe:07 on queue 1, stopping BA session on TID 0
[17961.097606] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unhandled alg: 0x703
[17961.097706] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unhandled alg: 0x703
[23421.542404] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: reached 20 old SN frames from e0:b9:e5:a6:fe:07 on queue 5, stopping BA session on TID 0
[24035.080548] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: reached 20 old SN frames from e0:b9:e5:a6:fe:07 on queue 4, stopping BA session on TID 0
[25202.244648] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: reached 20 old SN frames from e0:b9:e5:a6:fe:07 on queue 12, stopping BA session on TID 0


When the device is unclaimed, what results from terminal for sudo dmesg | grep iwl

@Jeremy31 good question! I will have to wait for the next update to find out, but will modify my post to include the current output in case it is helpful.

Does iwconfig show power management on?

You can try this echo "options iwlwifi options iwlwifi 11n_disable=4"|sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlopt.conf reboot
